# Make a concave navbar with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to make my footer navbar slightly concave instead of horizontal. Anyone know of a good way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I wasn't to descriptive before. I'm trying to do something like the following. The tan part would be the navbar footer:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Changing the border radius on the div above the footer worked. Here's what I did:

```
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30% 20%;
  z-index: 5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b7af98;
```

Comment: Can you show what you're working with?  By guessing what you mean, I think this can be achieved by modifying the `border-radius` css property.

Comment: example shape, http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ .. see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cogent/6A5Lb/)

Comment: @icanc, see the picture I added for what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

and since you want this done to a footer, you may want to try :

```
footer {
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I ended up changing the border-bottom properties on the div above the footer. See the second update for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a background image in one of your existing elements.